# Blurry font in Intellj(osx) on external monitor

Tags: fonts, intellij-idea, anti-aliasing

I'm running Intellij in my macbook pro latest gen. Font are crystal clear.
Now I have hooked a 2nd monitor (ViewSonic, 1080p) and fonts it are very bad, they look kind of blurry, here is a screenshot

If I zoom on the code screen font is perfect:

We can clearly see that on the first pic there is a kind of light cloud 
Does someone now how to fix this ?

thanks!

Comment: Looks fine to me - you have to bear in mind your additional monitor has less than half the pixel count of your main screen.

Comment: I don't think this is fine, there is clearly something not right. if I zoom on the code (on the external monitor) font are perfect (i have edited my question)

Comment: the test, now you can look at both pictures in here, is to see what they both look like on both screens. To me it just looks like retina vs HD, one is twice the rez of the other & consequently has far better antialiasing.

Answer (score 4):

The blurring is caused by the [anti-aliasing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spatial_anti-aliasing) and the fact that the external screen has bigger pixels, which makes the blurring visible. You can try disable anti-aliasing, but it's questionable whether the end result looks better:

[image]

You can also try to find a [bitmap font](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_font#Bitmap_fonts) (or just a different font), which may look better. Anti-aliasing usually doesn't apply to bitmap fonts.

PS: when you zoom on the code, your screen still has the same blurring as before, you just don't notice it that much because characters are bigger:

[image]